# Embedded Google Earth Plug-Ins no longer working

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I really hope someone can help me. I just noticed that none of my website's Google Earth embedded plug-in's work anymore (in Safari, Chrome or Firefox)  All you can see now is blank space and small text that says "Information is temporarily unavailable."

I have no idea why they would no longer be working.  Nothing has changed whatsoever.

Example here: http://www.grandcanyonvirtualtour.com/_tours/phantom_ranch.html

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!!

Please note, I am not a coder -- I am a photographer who is learning how to integrate photographs into maps, so I apologize if any questions are elementary.

Thanks,
Sara

I am on a MacBook Pro 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7; OS 10.7.4

Answer (score 0):

According to the generated code [here](http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/embedkmlgadget.xml), your embedded Google Earth gadget should be in a `script` element, e.g.:

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/embedkmlgadget.xml&amp;up_kml_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grandcanyonvirtualtour.com%2F_kml%2Fgrand_canyon_fly_thru_tour.kmz&amp;up_view_mode=earth&amp;up_earth_2d_fallback=0&amp;up_earth_fly_from_space=1&amp;up_earth_show_nav_controls=1&amp;up_earth_show_buildings=1&amp;up_earth_show_terrain=1&amp;up_earth_show_roads=1&amp;up_earth_show_borders=1&amp;up_earth_sphere=earth&amp;up_maps_zoom_out=0&amp;up_maps_default_type=map&amp;synd=open&amp;w=500&amp;h=400&amp;title=Embedded+KML+Viewer&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

However, looking at the website you've linked to, the gadget URL is inside an iframe, e.g.:

```
<iframe src="http://www.gmodules.com/..."
```

Maybe this is your problem?

Comment: thank you - I shall see if that makes a difference!  I made these quite awhile ago, and that must have been the code generated in an earlier incarnation (??)